# Get invisible decimal value in NSString objc

Tags: objective-c, string, decimal, invisible

I have a string with random names with an invisible decimal value  as prefix . The decimal = the names length. I need to retrieve the names. Obviously they are of different length. I want the names in an array so my idea is to use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString`. I implement the word "trunk" at the beginning and end of names. Though I am having trouble accessing the index corresponding at the end of the name (decimal value),  here is my code :

```
trimmed1 = [[trimmed1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:sp withString:@"trunk"]mutableCopy];

NSString *trunk = @"trunk%d";// add the ghost decimal at the end of prefix in order to get its value;

NSRange range =[trimmed1 rangeOfString:trunk];

int ghost= [trunk characterAtIndex:5];

NSMutableString *mu = [NSMutableString stringWithString:trimmed1];

[mu insertString : @"trunk" atIndex :range.location+range.length+ ghost];
```

I get the error `[__NSCFString insertString:atIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds`.

Comment: was it supposed to have a value for the string format %d ?NSString *trunk = @"trunk%d";

Comment: yes their is a decimal value that can vary

Comment: in that case shouldn't you have something like [NSString stringWithFormat:@"trunk%d", value];

Comment: well the value is random, I did not defined it, its been red from a data file. I thought leaving it @"trunk%d" xcode would understand it as any integer value. Xcode seems to be ok with it, got no semantic  error their, though I dont know if it does what is required.

Comment: well if it doesn't have a value for %d your trunk will only have "trunk" so indexing at 5 on a size 5 string will cause out of bounds exception

Comment: I get same error even if  ` int ghost= [trunk characterAtIndex:1];`

Comment: NSLog your trunk or create breakpoint to see what string value it has

Comment: NSLog do not print data values, or the debuger do not display it, but if I copy it to a file and open it in an hex editor I get "trunk05"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what `%d` means.

In a format used for *creating* a string it means "insert the value of an integer argument formatted as a string".

When *matching* one string against another it means "match the characters %d", I.e. it is not special in anyway.

You are getting an error as your string does not contain the characters "trunk%d". If you check the return value of `rangeOfString:` you will find it is returning a failure indication - read the documentation for how to test for that value.

For the simple task of matching an arbitrary decimal number trying looking at the `NSString` method `rangeOfCharactersFromSet:`.

You can also solve this problem with the classes `NSScanner` and `NSRegularExpression`.

HTH